# Merge live templates

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, live-templates

I have `PhpStorm` at home and at work. At both I add different live templates.

Also at home I try `WebStorm` where I add some another live templates.

1. Is there any posibility to merge different added live templates to leave all of them?
2. Can I import and merge live templates between `PhpStorm` and `WebStorm`?

Comment: 1) [PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119) 2) You can manually merge the config files -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs e.g. for PhpStorm (on Windows 10) it would typically be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2017.1\config\templates` folder . You may also try `File | Export/Import Settings...` but I'm not sure about "merging" part here at all (if such templates were created in the same group, then new will completely overwrite old ones AFAIK).

Comment: @LazyOne yes, templates overwriting on `Import` action. So as I understand I can merge templates only by manually merge xml files in `PhpStorm2017.1\config\templates` folder if I don't want totally overwrite them?

Comment: If they are in the same group (each group is stored in separate file) -- Yes. If you were clever/careful -- you have created your own templates in separate group(s) (as _ideally_ you should not edit bundled/provided-by-plugin templates/groups -- the max is to disable them -- less issues with them in future updates). Use groups -- they are convenient and easier to manage/share between users etc.

Comment: @LazyOne yes I create my own template group at begin. Only if I create language dependent templates I put in into existing group. For example I have template `todo`. In my own template group I create `//TODO $END$` but in html group I put it with code `<!-- TODO $END$ -->`

Comment: Better use own groups for ALL of your own stuff -- much less troubles/more convenient from all aspects.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for advice. I'll rewrite it into own language defined groups